# StoreKit for iOS - Subscriptions Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, storekit

I am using the new subscription model with `StoreKit` in a test application of mine, but I have a few questions:

- If the user cancels the subscription,
  how am I informed of this? Or do I
  have to monitor the date myself
  (using the value `transactionDate`)
- If the subscription is cancelled, the
  user can now longer restore this
  purchase if the subscription is
  expired right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't informed if the user cancels.  When you validate a receipt, Apple should give you a receipt for the most recent subscription period with a status of 0.  If this isn't the case, the user is no longer subscribed.

The user can't restore an expired subscription.

Comment: "The user can't restore an expired subscription." Are you sure, the Apple support stated sth different on a ticket of mine...

Comment: Were they talking about *restoring* (i.e. calling `restoreCompletedTransactions`)?  Your answer doesn't seem to be talking about restoring, it seems to be talking about re-buying.  Restoring is for when they have an active purchase and want to access it on a new device.